# How can i edit a bugged h1 text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div class="cart_holder">
  {% if cart.items != blank %}
    <div class="item_holder">
      {% for item in cart.items %}
        <a class="cart_item" href="{{ item.product.url }}">
          <img class="item_image" src="{{ item.product.image | product_image_url | constrain: 240, 240 }}" alt="Image of {{ item.product.name | escape }}">
          <div class="item_info">
            {{ item.product.name }}
            {% unless item.product.has_default_option %}
              <span>{{ item.option.name }}</span>
            {% endunless %}
            <div class="item_price">{{ item.unit_price | money: theme.money_format }}</div>
          </div>
        </a>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="cart_footer">
      <div class="item_subtotal">
        <span style="float:left">Ár:</span> <span style="float:right">{{ cart.total | money: theme.money_format }}</span>
      </div>
      <a class="button view_bag" href="/cart">Tovább a fizetéshez!</a>
    </div>
  {% else %}
    <div>
      A kosara üres
    </div>
    <a class="button view_bag" href="/products">Vásároljon Most!</a>
  {% endif %}
</div>

{% if cart.items != blank %}
  <h1>A kosara</h1>
  <form method="post" action="/cart" id="cart_form" class="cart_form">
    {% if errors != blank %}
      <ul class="errors">
        {% for error in errors %}
          <li>{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    {% endif %}
    <ul class="cart_items">
      {% for item in cart.items %}
        <li class="cart_item" data-cart-id="{{ item.id }}">
          <a href="{{ item.product.url }}" class="item_image" title="View {{ item.product.name }}">
            <img src="{{ item.product.image | product_image_url | constrain: 576 }}">
          </a>
          <div class="item_details">
            <a href="{{ item.product.url }}">
              {{ item.product.name }}
              {% unless item.product.has_default_option %}
                <span>{{ item.option.name }}</span>
              {% endunless %}
              <span class="price">{{ item.unit_price | money: theme.money_format }}</span>
            </a>
            <div class="qty_holder" data-cart-id="{{ item.id }}">
              <button class="qty" type="button" data-func="minus"><svg viewBox="0 0 20 20"><path d="M5 9h10v2H5z"/><path d="M5 9h10v2H5z"/></svg></button>
              {{ item | item_quantity_input, 'quantity', 'quantity' }}
              <button class="qty" type="button" data-func="plus"><svg viewBox="0 0 20 20"><path d="M11 5H9v4H5v2h4v4h2v-4h4V9h-4z"/></svg></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <div class="cart_info sticky">


      <h3>Ár:<span>{{ cart.total | money: theme.money_format }}</span></h3>
      <button type="submit" name="checkout" title="Tovább a fizetéshez!" class="checkout_btn">Tovább a fizetéshez!</button>
      <a class="button continue_shopping" href="/products">Folytassa a vásárlást</a>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="cart_empty_message" style="display: none;">
    <p><svg viewBox="0 0 30 30"><path d="M22.7 8c-.9-3.4-4-6-7.7-6S8.2 4.6 7.3 8H2l3 20h20l3-20h-5.3zM15 4c2.6 0 4.8 1.7 5.6 4H9.3c.9-2.3 3.1-4 5.7-4zm8.3 22H6.7L4.3 10H7v3h2v-3h12v3h2v-3h2.7l-2.4 16z"/></svg></p>
    <p><a class="button" href="/products">Vásároljon Most!</a></p>
  </div>
{% else %}
  <h1>A kosara üres</h1>
  <div class="cart_empty_message">
    <p><svg viewBox="0 0 30 30"><path d="M22.7 8c-.9-3.4-4-6-7.7-6S8.2 4.6 7.3 8H2l3 20h20l3-20h-5.3zM15 4c2.6 0 4.8 1.7 5.6 4H9.3c.9-2.3 3.1-4 5.7-4zm8.3 22H6.7L4.3 10H7v3h2v-3h12v3h2v-3h2.7l-2.4 16z"/></svg></p>
    <p><a class="button" href="/products">Vásároljon Most!</a></p>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

Hi! So this is my code, and the problem is that the first h1 tag is somehow bugged with the 2nd one, and i can't change the text, if i delete the 1 st h1 tag, the second one will not appear, only if i reload the page. Is there a way to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: So instead of posting server templating, click [edit] and then `[<>]` and produce one or more [mcve] with HTML and CSS only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems you're using liquid if statements.
So 1st you're checking if the cart is empty, if it isn't it executes the 1st `<h1>`

Try `{% if cart.item_count == 0 %}`
or read this [Shopify form post](https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-design/add-message-to-cart-screen-when-empty/td-p/639618)